# Applying Binary Search to Program

Tags: c#, sorting, search, binary

I currently have a program in which I read in files and sort using the bubble sort. However I need to implement a function that allows me to search through any of the files for a value. The algorithm I want to use is the Binary Search but I am unsure in how to implement this.

How would I make it so that I could choose a file to search through for a value which I enter?

Code used to read in files and allow to be sorted ( No help needed with sorting them):

```
var fileData = GetFileData(@"Data1/Day_1.txt", @"Data1/Depth_1.txt", 
    @"Data1/IRIS_ID_1.txt", @"Data1/Latitude_1.txt", @"Data1/Longitude_1.txt", 
    @"Data1/Magnitude_1.txt", @"Data1/Month_1.txt", @"Data1/Region_1.txt", 
    @"Data1/Time_1.txt", @"Data1/Timestamp_1.txt", @"Data1/Year_1.txt");
```

Above part is from the Main method

```
public class FileData
{
    public int File1Value { get; set; }
    public decimal File2Value { get; set; }
    public int File3Value { get; set; }
    public decimal File4Value { get; set; }
    public decimal File5Value { get; set; }
    public decimal File6Value { get; set; }
    public string File7Value { get; set; }
    public string File8Value { get; set; }
    public float File9Value { get; set; }
    public int File10Value { get; set; }
    public int File11Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format($"{File1Value}|{File2Value}|{File3Value}|{File4Value}|{File5Value}|{File6Value}|{File7Value}|{File8Value}|{File9Value}|{File10Value}|{File11Value}");
    }
}

public static FileData[] GetFileData(string firstFilePath, string secondFilePath, 
    string thirdFilePath, string fourthFilePath, string fifthFilePath, 
    string sixthFilePath, string seventhFilePath, string eigthFilePath, 
    string ninthFilePath, string tenthFilePath, string eleventhFilePath)
{

    int intHolder = 0;
    decimal decHolder = 0;
    float time = 0;

    // Get a list of ints from the first file
    var fileOneValues = File
        .ReadAllLines(firstFilePath)
        .Where(line => int.TryParse(line, out intHolder))
        .Select(v => intHolder)
        .ToArray();

    // Get a list of decimals from the second file
    var fileTwoValues = File
        .ReadAllLines(secondFilePath)
        .Where(line => decimal.TryParse(line, out decHolder))
        .Select(v => decHolder)
        .ToArray();

    var fileThreeValues = File
        .ReadAllLines(thirdFilePath)
        .Where(line => int.TryParse(line, out intHolder))
        .Select(v => intHolder)
        .ToArray();

    var fileFourValues = File
        .ReadAllLines(fourthFilePath)
        .Where(line => decimal.TryParse(line, out decHolder))
        .Select(v => decHolder)
        .ToArray();

    var fileFiveValues = File
        .ReadAllLines(fifthFilePath)
        .Where(line => decimal.TryParse(line, out decHolder))
        .Select(v => decHolder)
        .ToArray();

    var fileSixValues = File
       .ReadAllLines(sixthFilePath)
       .Where(line => decimal.TryParse(line, out decHolder))
       .Select(v => decHolder)
       .ToArray();

    var fileSevenValues = File
        .ReadAllLines(seventhFilePath)
        .ToArray();

    var fileEightValues = File
        .ReadAllLines(eigthFilePath)
        .ToArray();

    var fileNineValues = File
        .ReadAllLines(ninthFilePath)
        .Where(line => float.TryParse(line, out time))
        .Select(v => time)
        .ToArray();

    var fileTenValues = File
        .ReadAllLines(tenthFilePath)
        .Where(line => int.TryParse(line, out intHolder))
        .Select(v => intHolder)
        .ToArray();

    var fileElevenValues = File
        .ReadAllLines(eleventhFilePath)
        .Where(line => int.TryParse(line, out intHolder))
        .Select(v => intHolder)
        .ToArray();

    // I guess the file lengths should match, but in case they don't, 
    // use the size of the smaller one so we have matches for all items
    var numItems = Math.Min(fileOneValues.Count(), fileTwoValues.Count());

    // Populate an array of new FileData objects
    var fileData = new FileData[numItems];
    for (var index = 0; index < numItems; index++)
    {
        fileData[index] = new FileData
        {
            File1Value = fileOneValues[index],
            File2Value = fileTwoValues[index],
            File3Value = fileThreeValues[index],
            File4Value = fileFourValues[index],
            File5Value = fileFiveValues[index],
            File6Value = fileSixValues[index],
            File7Value = fileSevenValues[index],
            File8Value = fileEightValues[index],
            //File9Value = fileNineValues[index],
            File10Value = fileTenValues[index],
            File11Value = fileElevenValues[index]
        };
    }

    return fileData;
}
```

Code of Binary Search:

```
  static int BinarySearch_R(int key, FileData[] fileData, int low, int high)
{
    if (low > high) return -1;
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    if (key == fileData[mid])
    {

        return mid;
    }
    if (key < fileData[mid])
    {
        return BinarySearch_R(key, fileData, low, mid - 1);
    }
    else
    {

        return BinarySearch_R(key, fileData, mid + 1, high);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you returning `object` from your `BinarySearchIterative` method? Shouldn't it return an `int`? Or is there a need for the string `"Nil"`?

Comment: This binary search isnt at the moment included in my program. Thats what I have been trying to implement from a stock answer I had used before. I should have made that clear.

Comment: What is the question exactly? There's a lot of code posted - which part is giving you trouble?

Comment: Actually implementing a Binary search into my code. So that I can choose a file I would like to search through and then enter a value. The binary search is then performed and if the value is present a message appears.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see where you've tried that, or where it's failing.

Comment: The problem I have is that whenever I do so it will come up with an error like cannot convert Program.FileType to int or something along those lines. I'll edit the code in a min to show you

Comment: Well, it looks like your files are of different types: `int`, `decimal`, `string`, and `float`. Is that the issue? Does it work with any of the file types? Where is your implementation of the part that's not working?

Comment: I updated the code with what I tired to do. The error appears on the key part. I kind of understand why but Im not sure how I can apply this to all data types.

Comment: The `GetFileData` method is not relevant to your question. You should remove that code (but leave the definition for the `FileData` class and the binary search method), and show the code where you're actually trying to call the binary search. What values are you passing to it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for a way to make your BinarySearch method generic, so that it will work on different types of objects.

Below I've changed the first one you posted to be generic, where the type `T` is constrained to types that implement `IComparable<T>` (since we need to be able to compare the `key` with items in the `inputArray` inside the method).

This should work for the types you have defined for your files (`int`, `decimal`, `string`, and `float` all implement `IComparable`).

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the index of an item in inputArray that matches the value of key
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of objects in the array</typeparam>
/// <param name="inputArray">An array of items to search</param>
/// <param name="key">A key item value to search for</param>
/// <returns>The index of an item that matches key, or -1 if no match is found</returns>
public static int BinarySearchIterative<T>(T[] inputArray, T key) 
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    int min = inputArray.GetLowerBound(0);
    int max = inputArray.GetUpperBound(0);

    while (min <= max)
    {
        int mid = (min + max) / 2;
        int comparison = key.CompareTo(inputArray[mid]);

        if (comparison == 0)
        {
            return mid;
        }
        else if (comparison < 0)
        {
            max = mid - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            min = mid + 1;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. I'll try in the morning, pretty late here. I will let you know how I get on .

Comment: To call this in the main I would use an if statement but inside this what would be used to pass the value through to the binary search if you get me?